# Moment JS objects updating when setting them into new variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

This is something that has always baffled me, and i think its about time I got my head around it, so could someone possibly explain it to me and how to fix it?

Ok, so im using moment JS to create a time object, like so

```
var startOfDiscount = moment('24/07/2018', "DD/MM/YYYY");
```

Why is it that when I try to create a new variable based off my `startOfDiscount` object like this

```
var endOfDiscount = startOfDiscount.add(6, 'months').endOf('month');
```

That is changes my `startOfDiscount` object to? I know that the line `startOfDiscount.add(1, 'months').endOf('month')` is manipulating the actual `startOfDiscount` object, but how do i do it so that it only manipulates/changes for the purpose of my new variable, and the original variable stays the same?

So if I ran

```
console.log(startOfDiscount);
console.log(endOfDiscount);
```

They both print the same date?

Why is javascript changing the original object/variable when I try to use it to declare a new one. How do I do it so that the changes to my original object are only for the purposes of setting my new variable?

This is something that i've never been able to understand why it happens and how to prevent it. Could someone possibly explain why it does this and how to prevent it please?

Comment: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/add/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're correct that it changes the original, though this is by design. Here is a link to the [documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/)

> Mutates the original moment by adding time.

```js
var startOfDiscount = moment('24/07/2018', "DD/MM/YYYY");
var endOfDiscount = startOfDiscount.add(6, 'months').endOf('month');

console.log(startOfDiscount);
console.log(endOfDiscount);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

If you want to make a new variable based on the old variable you first have to [clone](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/clone/) it.

> Create a clone of a duration. Durations are mutable, just like moment objects, so this lets you get a snapshot, at some point in time.

```js
var startOfDiscount = moment('24/07/2018', "DD/MM/YYYY");
var endOfDiscount = startOfDiscount.clone().add(6, 'months').endOf('month');

console.log(startOfDiscount);
console.log(endOfDiscount);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

I hope this makes sense. Generally, with big libraries like this, the documentation is very good and worth a read.

https://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: I was under the impression that this sort of behaviour is not just moment js but a general rule with javascript objects? Do I have to use the same clone function when working with any javascript objects?

Comment: `Clone` is a momentJS specific function. Some function in JS will mutate and other will just return a new object/array you can look up any default function on https://developer.mozilla.org/

Comment: Ahh ok, so this sort of behaviour is just based on whether the library mutates or copies an object and is library specific? I think i understand now, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

> Could someone possibly explain why it does this ...

Because the chained methods return their context like this:

```
moment.prototype.add = function(n, type) {
  //...
  return this;
};
```

That allows you to do chaining like:

```
moment().add(1, "months").add(2, "days");
```

But it also means that `startOfDiscount.add(1, "months")` evaluates to `startOfDiscount`, so if you assign that to another variable, you got two references to the same object.

> ... and how to prevent it please?

Just create a new moment object, then mutate that:

```
var endOfDiscount = moment(startOfDiscount).add(6, 'months').endOf('month');
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to clone it like

```
var endOfDiscount = startOfDiscount.clone().add...
```

check this https://momentjs.com/guides/